# What's the basis on flagging a question as a duplicate

Tags: discussion

I was just curious about something but say one identification request question was a memory/description based one only and there was another identification request question ***but*** it was an image only one with a little back link to where he/she found it ***but*** both had exactly the same answer and was accepted by the two different OP's in this case.

Would it be a duplicate question or not?

I mean sure and all they might be a little different in terms of how it was asked, but they both have the same answer I guess. Would it still count as a duplicate though? I haven't actually flagged any like this but I was curious to know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Two questions are duplicate if and only if they have the exact same answer. Also, if the two question have exactly the same wording (and usually come from the same OP) they are considered duplicates as well.